# Bash script for psql

Tags: psql

Here is the shell script I am trying to run. It works when just run as a command but getting errors when run from the script.

```
#!/bin/bash

# sets CE IP addresses to act as LUS on pgsql

#Checks that user is logged in as root
if [ $(id -u) = "0" ]; then
        #Asks user for IP of CE1
        echo -n "Enter the IP address of your first CE's management module > "
        read CE1

        $(psql -U asm -d asm -t -c) echo """update zr_fsinstance set lu_order='1' where     managementaccesspointhostname = '$CE1';"""

        echo "LUS seetings have been completed"

else
        #Warns user of error and sends status to stderr
        echo "You must be logged in as root to run this script." >&2
        exit 1
fi
```

Here is the error:

```
psql: option requires an argument -- 'c'
Try "psql --help" for more information.
update zr_fsinstance set lu_order='1' where managementaccesspointhostname = '10.134.39.139';
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of

```
$(psql -U asm -d asm -t -c) echo 
"""update zr_fsinstance 
set lu_order='1' where managementaccesspointhostname = '$CE1';"""
```

Try:

```
$(psql -U asm -d asm -t -c "UPDATE zr_fsinstance set lu_order='1' 
  where managementaccesspointhostname = ${CE1};")
```

OR (if you prefer):

```
`psql -U asm -d asm -t -c "UPDATE zr_fsinstance set lu_order='1' 
 where managementaccesspointhostname = ${CE1};"`
```

Comment: This is what I ended up using: COMMAND=$'psql -U asm -d asm -t -c \"update zr_fsinstance set lu_order=\'1\' where managementaccesspointhostname = \''$CE1\'';"'
        echo $COMMAND
        eval $COMMAND